# Crate DB Snapshot size

Tags: cratedb

I have setup a python script which creates a crate db snapshot everyday at noon.
The query I ran to setup the repo is:

`CREATE REPOSITORY repo_name TYPE FS WITH (LOCATION='/path/to/folder', compress=true);`

The query I run everyday in order to create the snapshot is:

`CREATE SNAPSHOT repo_name.{} ALL WITH (wait_for_completion=true, ignore_unavailable=true);`

On the initial run, the snapshot directory size was same as the database size (30GB).

After about a month, the database has grown to 40GB while the snapshot directory size has grown to ~120GB (almost thrice the size of the database!).

Is this normal?

If yes, are there any options/optimizations I can try out to reduce the size of the snapshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Crate](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/sql/statements/create-repository.html#fs) the **table data is not compressed**. Only metadata is compressed. (I agree it's confusing.)

Snapshots are [incremental](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/sql/statements/create-snapshot.html) so I'm not entirely sure why this has grown so much. (Do you perhaps ingest a lot of data that is then perhaps removed but still present during the snapshot?) May be worth raising a query with Crate directly on their github and checking if this is a bug or not.